# Ajax request not working locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script where I am doing an Ajax request to the server:

```
var answers = JSON.stringify(Controller);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/utdanningstesten/ws/answers/",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : "application/json",
    data: answers,
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
        if (lang === 'nb') {
            window.location.replace("/utdanningstesten/resultPage.php?id="+res);
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("/utdanningstesten/resultPage.php?id="+res+'&lang='+lang);
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            console.log('HTTP error');
        }
        else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
            console.log('Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.)');
        }
        else {
            console.log('something weird');
        }
    }
});
}else{
    //$('.btnG').append('<div class="alert">');
    blink('.btnG', 6, 150)
}
```

And this works fine on the live server, when I am trying to test this on the local server, with the local address `http://velgriktig.dev:8888` it doesn't work. In the console I get that the request to that endpoint is pending, no errors, just pending forever.I have tried with adding also `http://velgriktig.dev:8888` to the endpoint, so that I have the full URL, but that didn't help either, why can't I get this work locally?

Comment: is the script and /utdanningstesten/ws/answers/ running in the same server. looks like cross origin issue

Comment: Is the endpoint accessible via postman or rest client in your local?

Comment: When you go in browser to url `http://velgriktig.dev:8888` does it responds fine or with errors? Maybe your local server is not working properly?